# How do I get mobs and pigmen to spawn in the Nether again?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Pigmen were always spawning in my nether, but I went 1 time in game mode 1 and now pigmen aren't spawning anymore.  Is there a way to fix it?  Or is there a way to reset the spawning rates of mobs in the Nether?

**Edit:** The solution is in the answers its my own answer but still thanks for the help ;D

Comment: Are you in peaceful mode?

Comment: Are you in peaceful mode? Because other than that Game-mode 1 should not effect spawn rates.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys after a lot of research i found the solution its weard but you have to put you render distance on 10 chunks or more it helped me so i hope that is also helps you :)